# How do I tighten a loose kitchen faucet?

Tags: faucet

I have a kitchen faucet that is starting to move around in the hole cut in the counter top. I would like to figure out how to tighten it, but due to the location of drain pipes and the disposal I can't get my head back there. I can reach up, but I don't know what I am supposed to be doing.

I took a picture back there, but I am not really sure what I am supposed to do to tighten it.

[image]

[image: enter code here]

Comment: What is the make of the faucet? Do you know the model name or number? A picture of the faucet itself might help. It looks to me like that silver rectangle is some sort of a clip. Is this a super-fancy faucet? I can't tell what the BX conduit is for, or where it is going? Are those the sprayer hoses?

Comment: I am not sure of the make of the faucet. It was in the house when I bought it and I don't see anywhere that it is labeled. I added a photo of it though. The conduit is for the head of the faucet (it pulls out like a spray hose).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tool you need to get behind the sink to tighten the retainer nut is called a basin wrench.  You can buy them anywhere for $8 to $40.  They swivel to fit and have extended handle so you can turn it from below the sink level.  Yes, you have to do it by sense of feel, or position a mirror to help you see the nut. Google sink wrench or basin wrench and you will see dozens of them.

Plumb Pak PP840-7 11 Inch Basin Wrench
$8 online

Comment: Thanks for the help. Guess I now need 1 more tool to add to my bag.

Comment: Adding tools to your bag becomes an addiction when you own a house and DIY.  LOL. But still cheaper and better than calling someone like me to bring my tool bag and leave you with a big bill...!!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a Moen to me. The end of the pull-out hose opposite from the sprayer head should be attached to a short length of threaded pipe. This threaded pipe also has a nut on it that holds the faucet tight to the counter top. I think this nut is usually tightened with a specialty tool that comes with the faucet, so it might be a bit inconvenient to do it with a standard basin wrench.