# How do I tighten a PVC fitting in a narrow space behind a sink?

Tags: sink, pvc

I've recently replaced the tap and handles in an old bathroom sink. It turned out to be a bit of a pain because the bolts holding the sink in are rusted into the besser block wall - the bolt head just snapped off the first bolt I tired to unscrew. I decided to leave the sink as is and just try and replace the tap and handles like that. I managed, but now I'm having a really hard time tightening up the PVC pipe fitting under tap because it's in such a tight position.

So my question is, are there any techniques or tools for tightening up such things when they're in such a tight place? I have 3 cm or less space in any given direction due the wall on one side and surrounding sink.

Comment: What type of nut is on the fitting? Is it knurled,hex shaped or have two wings protruding from the sides?

Comment: Related http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/how-do-i-tighten-a-loose-kitchen-faucet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tighten a loose kitchen faucet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/how-do-i-tighten-a-loose-kitchen-faucet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a basin wrench. It cams sort of like a pipe wrench, so it should be able to grip almost anything. Insert the handle from the other side to cam the other direction.

[image: Basin Wrench]

Answer (score 2):

Does the nut have thumb tabs to turn?  A photo is key for the best answers here.  If it does, I make these on my own with a piece of PVC pipe and they work like a charm for installing/uninstalling sink faucets.  Just run a piece of pipe vertically through your table saw to make two kerf cuts at 90 degree angles.

[image]